# Leaflet e.target.getLatLng() not working when paired with markercluster

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leafet (django-leaflet to be more precise) and I've been able to form a .on(click) on any marker so that it pans to the marker and zooms in to zoom 10.  This is done by using map.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),10);

However, I have now implemented [leaflet markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/) and it seems that the getLatLng() is an undefined function now?

Code without markercluster, which works perfectly:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name).on('click', clickZoomy);

            function clickZoomy(e) {
              if (map.getZoom() < 10){
                map.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),10) //ZOOM
              } else{
                map.setView(e.target.getLatLng())
              }};
```

Here is the code I'm using with markercluster:

```
var multimarker = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

multimarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.526013, 13.398351],{icon: markHospital})).on('click', clickZoom);
multimarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.513666, 13.389633],{icon: markHospital})).on('click', clickZoom);
multimarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.512842, 13.389277],{icon: markHospital})).on('click', clickZoom);

map.addLayer(multimarker);  function clickZoom(e) {
    map.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),10)};
```

Comment: Better example. setView will work with the lone point at the bottom but not with with markercluster. (var mmarker = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

    mmarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.526013, 13.398351])).on('click', clickZoom);
    mmarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.513666, 13.389633])).on('click', clickZoom);
    mmarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.512842, 13.389277],)).on('click', clickZoom);

    map.addLayer(mmarker);
    
    L.marker([51.941196,4.512291]).addTo(map).on('click', clickZoom);
      
      function clickZoom(e) {
        map.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),10)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had parenthesis in the wrong place.

```
multimarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.526013, 13.398351],{icon: markHospital})).on('click', clickZoom);
```

had to be changed to

```
multimarker.addLayer(L.marker([52.526013, 13.398351],{icon: markHospital}).on('click', clickZoom));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please can you accept your answer so that people know your issue is solved? Thank you!